# How to optimize hyperparameters in stacked model?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter, ensemble-learning, stacking

I was wondering whether somebody could explain how to optimize hyperparameters for the base learners and meta algorithm when stacking? In many tutorials they seem to be plucked out of thin air!

Thanks,

Jack